# Doctrine: как doctrine отслеживает изменения названий таблиц в маппинге @Column

Tags: symfony3, doctrine2

Имеется класс, в бд уже лежат кое-какие данные:

```
class Me
{
    /**
     * @Column(name="field",type="string")
     */
    $field;

    /**
     * @Column(name="fieldTwo",type="int")
     */
    $fieldTwo;
}
```

Меняю в маппинге название столбца первого поля: field --> some_field

```
class Me
{
    /**
     * @Column(name="some_field",type="string")
     */
    $field;

    /**
     * @Column(name="fieldTwo",type="int")
     */
    $fieldTwo;
}
```

Запускаю

```
doctrine:schema:update
```

Ожидаю, что Доктрина просто забудет про старый столбец field и создаст новый some_field. 
Но доктрина ***как-то*** понимает, что нужно именно переименовать существующий столбец, вместо того, чтобы забыть про старый и создать новый. Что в голове плохо укладывается.
Кто-то сталкивался с таким поведением, чем оно обусловлено, как им управлять?

P.S. Замечу, что  никаких данных о маппинге в файлах проекта доктрнина не создавала, разработка code-first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как оказалось, все законно.
При:

```
doctine:scheme:update
```

Вызывается метод класса Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Comparator [compare()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Schema.Comparator.html#85-156), в котором последовательно сравниваются все таблицы на наличие изменений:

```
foreach ($toSchema->getTables() as $table) {
        $tableName = $table->getShortestName($toSchema->getName());
        if ( ! $fromSchema->hasTable($tableName)) {
            $diff->newTables[$tableName] = $toSchema->getTable($tableName);
        } else {
            $tableDifferences = $this->diffTable($fromSchema->getTable($tableName), $toSchema->getTable($tableName));
            if ($tableDifferences !== false) {
                $diff->changedTables[$tableName] = $tableDifferences;
            }
        }
    }
```

Смотрим код [diffTable()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Schema.Comparator.html#194-306):

```
foreach ($table2Columns as $columnName => $column) {
    if ( !$table1->hasColumn($columnName)) {
        $tableDifferences->addedColumns[$columnName] = $column;
        $changes++;
    }
}
/* See if there are any removed fields in table 2 */
foreach ($table1Columns as $columnName => $column) {
    // See if column is removed in table 2.
    if ( ! $table2->hasColumn($columnName)) {
        $tableDifferences->removedColumns[$columnName] = $column;
        $changes++;
        continue;
    }
```

Как я и предполагал, доктрина составляет список тех столбцов, которых нет в БД в данный момент и список столбцов, которые присутствуют в новом маппинге, но отсутствуют в БД.
Но дальше в diffTable после этого вызывается метод [detectColumnRenamings()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Schema.Comparator.html#308-340), в котором и происходит вся магия:

```
 this->detectColumnRenamings($tableDifferences);
```

Его код:

```
private function detectColumnRenamings(TableDiff $tableDifferences)
{
    $renameCandidates = array();
    foreach ($tableDifferences->addedColumns as $addedColumnName => $addedColumn) {
        foreach ($tableDifferences->removedColumns as $removedColumn) {
            if (count($this->diffColumn($addedColumn, $removedColumn)) == 0) {
                $renameCandidates[$addedColumn->getName()][] = array($removedColumn, $addedColumn, $addedColumnName);
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($renameCandidates as $candidateColumns) {
        if (count($candidateColumns) == 1) {
            list($removedColumn, $addedColumn) = $candidateColumns[0];
            $removedColumnName = strtolower($removedColumn->getName());
            $addedColumnName = strtolower($addedColumn->getName());

            if ( ! isset($tableDifferences->renamedColumns[$removedColumnName])) {
                $tableDifferences->renamedColumns[$removedColumnName] = $addedColumn;
                unset($tableDifferences->addedColumns[$addedColumnName]);
                unset($tableDifferences->removedColumns[$removedColumnName]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Если почитать код метода (а еще лучше комментарии к нему :) ), а так же посмотреть, что делает метод [diffColumn()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Schema.Comparator.html#425-498) (возвращает изменения двух произвольных столбцов), то становится понятно, что:

- При наличии в новом маппинге и в существующей БД по одному идентичному полю (тип, длина и т.д. кому интересен полный список критериев, добро пожаловать в метод [diffColumn()](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Schema.Comparator.html#425-498)), то столбец будет переименован.
- Если же таких столбцов на одной из сторон (старый и новый маппинги) больше одного, то доктрина создаст новый пустой столбец, старый оставит в покое.

Answer (score 1):

У вас анатации к свойству класса.
Свойства не измененно, аннатация обновлённая, следовательно доктрина обновляет имя.

Doctrina посмотрела на класс сущности и сравнила его c текущей версией БД, увидела разницу и как следсnвия обновила.

Кстати у Symfony есть бандл DoctrineMigrationsBundle  который позволяет хранить состояни версии базы данных. Но это уже другая тем и квопросу отношения не имеет.

Comment: Как доктрина понимает, что аннотация обновленная, на основании чего? Где она хранит состояние того, что было до исправления? Фактически название столбца было заменено, как она поняла, что оно было заменено?

Comment: Ну это аннатация не сама по себе, она работае в паре с свойствам класса.Она посмотрела на класс сущности и сравнила его текущей версией БД, увидела разницу и как следсвия обновила.

Comment: Давайте попробуем побыть доктриной. Нам говорят doctrine:schema:update. Я смотрю в маппинг, вижу, что в классе есть поле $fieldTwo, у поля есть аннотация @Column(name="fieldTwo"). Я смотрю в БД в таблицу - такой столбец есть, ничего не делаю. Далее, очередное поле - $field, аннотация  @Column(name="some_field") . Смотрю в БД в таблицу - такого поля нет!  Я должен создать новый столбец в таблице. Но, доктрина КАК-ТО понимает, что у этого поля раньше была другая аннотация. КАК и НА ОСНОВАНИИ ЧЕГО она это определяет? Где она хранит предыдущее состояние маппинга?

Comment: Вот класс обновления смотрите сами. http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.SchemaTool.html#842-860

Comment: Вы на все вопросы отправляете читать исходники библиотек, или только на те, на которые не знаете ответа?

Comment: Я та как раз ответ знаю и его уже дал. В ролевые игры играть с вами не собираюсь. Если мой ответ не удовлетворяет ваши ожидания и это сугубо ваше личное дело. При выполнении это команды создаются 2 объекта  $fromSchema и $toSchema  один на основания базы данных другой на основание метаданных.

Comment: Если бы вы сами последовали своему совету и посмотрели исходники доктрины, то могли бы увидеть вызов метода diffTable в классе Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Comparator (http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.0/source-class-Doctrine.DBAL.Schema.Comparator.html#194-306), в котором реализована как-раз та логика, о которой я говорил: удаление несуществующих столбцов, добавление новых. За исключением одного интересного момента, который и ведет к переименованию столбца. Замечу, что в общем случае вы дали неверный, ответ, пояснения смотрите в моем ответе.

Comment: Плохо вы читаете код. 1.Там даже комментарий есть.  // See if column has changed properties in table

Comment: Код я прочитал и увидел. Ответ оформить занимает какое-то время. Вы может быть даже и знали ответ на вопрос, но согласитесь, на этом ресурсе получать ответы "вот тебе ссылка на исходники библиотеки из не одного десятка классов, читай"  как-то не ожидаешь. Тем более вы дали ссылку не на тот класс. Следуя вашей логике на все вопросы по симфони можно давать ссылку на гитхаб репозиторий со словами "разбирайся" :)